# C# - Webbrowser control change case of text input in form

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, keypress

I have this app that runs a webpage. One input on the page has to be in uppercase. The webpage is coded in Javascript and unfortunately, I can't use the normal way with webbrowser to intercept the form field and change it. (Like if I search the source code, I don't have any input fields in the "form")...

I was wondering if there is a way to capture keyboard input or something like that with webbrowser? I found you can use PreviewKeyDown but unfortunately, when I use it to send back a uppercase letter, it send multiples keypress instead of just the one I did. So it's no good...

I know it's vague but I'm stuck at the moment and I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Edit : I found the HTML element of my input in my form... but still no ID present?

```
`<input name="s_2_1_1_0" tabindex="0" class="BLABLABLA s_2_1_1_0" aria-readonly="false"
 aria-describedby=" s_2_1_1_0_icon" aria-labelledby="NUMBER_Label" 
style="width: 136px; height: 24px;" aria-label="Serial #" 
type="text" placeholder="<Case Sensitive>" value="">    `
```

Comment: Do not try to sanitize data in the browser, do it in the server or consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a workaround.

I'm using :

```
`            HtmlElementCollection elems = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("s_2_1_1_0");
        var ele = webBrowser1.Document.All["s_2_1_1_0"];
        ele.TagName.ToLower();
        //MessageBox.Show(ele.GetAttribute("value"));
        //  MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Document.All.GetElementsByName("s_2_1_1_0").GetAttribute.ToString());

        ele.SetAttribute("value", ele.GetAttribute("value").ToUpper());    `
```